# Finding Value At Which There is the Largest and Smallest Value in a For-loop Array C++

Tags: c++

Alright, I have my code (shown below) which basically gets the largest and smallest temperature values for the entire year. Now that works, but where I'm having trouble is coming up with a solution to put out the incremented value "j" when the largest value is found in the array. I need this because the main goal of the program is to output the month in which the largest and smallest value is found. And I already have a function written in this code that will convert the incremented value into a string month.

TLDR:
I need to find out how to know at what value of "j" my program finds the maximum and minimum values.

So, if you guys could offer any insight into how I might accomplish this that would be fantastic!

```
     //Gathering Largest Temperature:
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        if(yearData[j].highTemperature > highestTemperature)
           highestTemperature = yearData[j].highTemperature;
    }

    //Gathering Smallest Temperature:
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        if(yearData[j].lowTemperature < lowestTemperature)
            lowestTemperature = yearData[j].lowTemperature;
    }
```

Comment: When you find a new high, save the current index in a variable that is declared outside the loop, just like you do with `highestTemperature`.

Comment: So yeah, I just thought of that the moment I got out of my seat. So it would be something like (under the if statement):     month = j;

Comment: Right (with braces on the if-statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Gathering Largest Temperature:
auto highestTemperature = yearData[0].highTemperature;
int highestTemperatureDate = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
{
    if(yearData[j].highTemperature > highestTemperature)
    {
       highestTemperature = yearData[j].highTemperature;
       highestTemperatureDate = j;
    }
}

//Gathering Smallest Temperature:
auto lowestTemperature = yearData[0].lowTemperature;
int smallestTemperatureDate = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
{
    if (yearData[j].lowTemperature < lowestTemperature)
    {
        lowestTemperature = yearData[j].lowTemperature;
        smallestTemperatureDate = j;
    }
}
```

I added an int for the smallest and highest temperatures

Comment: Jarod 42 i didn't understand your comment if i have a formatting error pls edit it

Comment: Thanks i just realised i missed the {}

Comment: You can combine the two loops into a single loop that compares both low and high temps on each iteration.

Comment: Yes but it's not the question

Answer (score 1):

With std, you might do:

```
//Gathering Largest Temperature:
auto max = std::max_element(std::begin(yearData), std::end(yearData),
                            [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){
                                return lhs.highTemperature < return rhs.highTemperature;
                            });

auto max_index = std::distance(std::begin(yearData), max);

// Gathering Smallest Temperature:
auto min = std::min_element(std::begin(yearData), std::end(yearData),
                            [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){
                                return lhs.lowTemperature < return rhs.lowTemperature;
                            });
auto min_index = std::distance(std::begin(yearData), min);
```